# How can character vectors from R be exported or copied to excel so that each element of the vector is assigned its own cell?

Tags: r, excel, vector

I have a character vector in R, of gene names that looks like this (this has been extracted from a data frame, whereby these genes meet certain criteria):

```
[66] "PIAS3"    "FGF18"    "na"       "PCDH8"    "CEBPB"    "VTN"      "PCYT1B"   "GRAMD1C"  "HS3ST3A1" "TMEM171"  "GADD45B"  "NUDT2"    "na"      
[79] "TPN"      "MAT1A"    "na"       "SHOX2"    "TUSC5"    "PALM"     "TBX3"     "C11ORF87" "SOX9"     "TBKBP1"   "GDAP1L1"  "Unchar10" "PIM1"
```

I would like to copy or export this to excel so that each character string (each element of the vector) has its own cell. At present, all the character strings in each row i.e

```
  "PIAS3"    "FGF18"    "na"       "PCDH8"    "CEBPB"    "VTN"      "PCYT1B"   "GRAMD1C"  "HS3ST3A1" "TMEM171"  "GADD45B"  "NUDT2"    "na"
```

, are pasted into a single cell.

Alternatively, if I could transform this character vector into a presentable table or list, within R, that would also solve my problem.

Any help would be gratefully received. Many thanks in advance. Martin

Comment: Are the number of elements in each vector the same?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to copy/paste, just type "as.data.frame(your.vector)". You'll get one element on each line allowing you to cut/paste easily. Else, look at write.csv(your.vector,"your.vector.csv") and open the resulting csv file in excel.

Comment: Dear Jim,thanks for the reply. The first option works, although it also copies the row number which is not ideal. Forgive my ignorance, but having created csv files as you directed, I have no idea where they are saved to. Thanks, Martin